# DB down on executing delete query

Tags: sql, database, cascade, cascading-deletes

Is there a possibility that a simple delete query can bring down a DB?

We executed a delete query (single row deletion) and that query hung. When multiple people tried executing the same delete again, the Oracle DB is down. 
Multiple tables reference this table and a cascade delete was not used. Should a cascade delete have been used?

What are the possible reasons for the DB to go down on executing this sql?

Comment: As Jerry McGuire said, "Show us the query!"

Answer (score 1):

The delete stmts hung, the db reached max number of allowed processes (which were waiting); and the db stopped establishing new connections. We killed the hanging processes and the db is up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's down and it's not just a transaction that has locked your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files of the server. My guess is that the delete modified a lot of rows and you ran out of UNDO log.